# How to have an autoincremented coordinate in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

I want to print a plot with pgfplots where I will have plenty of points. For now, I have something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            clip=false,
            xlabel=Batches, ylabel=Error,
            legend entries={Train error},
            ymin = 0, ymax = 1
        ]
        \addplot [mark=none] coordinates {
            (1, 0.7254)
            (2, 0.7254)
            (3, 0.7245)
            (4, 0.7200)
            (5, 0.7125)
            (6, 0.7112)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This works perfectly, but I'll have many more points and they'll likely come from a file and I'd like to avoid having the 1,2,3,4... indices. How can I automatically generate the x coordinate ? It's always starting at 1 and incrementing by one every value. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example where `data.dat` contains just a single column of numbers. The x-value is found using `x expr=\coordindex+1`.

```
% writes its contents to data.dat
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
0.7254
0.7254
0.7254
0.7200
0.7125
0.7112
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [
            clip=false,
            xlabel=Batches, ylabel=Error,
            legend entries={Train error},
            ymin = 0, ymax = 1
        ]
        \addplot [mark=none] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]